# How to reject an app that is waiting for review using iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I would like to reject a build in iTunes connect.  I submitted a new build, incrementing the build number but I don't see any option to select this new build and reject the old build.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: The question title and the actual question are two completely different this. Please fix.

Comment: @Juhana This site also welcomes questions about commonly used programming tools. iTunes Connect qualifies as a common tool used by iOS and OS X app developers.

Comment: I modified the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

When I came back today I saw a banner at the top of the page that allowed me to remove this version from review.